# axios get request not working in Edge browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am using axis get request with headers in the vuejs application. Working fine getting a response in chrome and firefox. But in edge it's not working, getting Network Error.

Comment: `its not working, getting Network Error` surely the error says more than just "Network Error" ... is this perhaps on a page loaded using `file:///` rather than http/https?

Comment: [object Error]: {config: Object, description: "Network Error", message: "Network Error", request: Object, response: undefined...}

config: Object
description: "Network Error"
message: "Network Error"

request: Object
response: undefined
stack: "Error: Network Error at e.exports (https://unpkg.com/axios@0.18.0/dist/axios.min.js:8:4473) at l.onerror (https://unpkg.com/axios@0.18.0/dist/axios.min.js:8:3317)"
This is my error in console

Comment: page loaded not using file:///, loaded using http://127.0.0.1:5500/

Comment: Open the developer console in Edge using the F12 key. Does it say anything else in the console? If you open the network tab in your developer console, does the offending request have any other information? Also, if you have any new information such as stacktraces, please edit your question instead of putting them in the comments. It is much easier to properly format them there, and they are not prone to being buried by other comments. It makes it a lot easier for other people to get all the information this question has to offer.

Comment: if we send get request without any header it will work fine. if i include header Authorization it shows error.

Comment: Please add all information to the question itself, including error messages, and some information about that header

Comment: @Nico I think they created a duplicate already, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55547550/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [axios get request with header Authorization not working on Edge browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55547550/axios-get-request-with-header-authorization-not-working-on-edge-browser)