# axios get request with header Authorization not working on Edge browser

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am using axios get request with  headers in vuejs application. Working fine and getting response in chrome and firefox. But in edge its not working, getting Network Error. I am sending the request with header Authorization.

```
 axios.get(url, {
    headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic bmlwerydmFdfgdfgdfllobjhJayw='
   }
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log("Success");
   }
  }).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
 });
```

showing following error in console.

```
 [object Error]: {config: Object, description: "Network Error", message: 
 "Network Error", request: Object, response: undefined...}

   config: Object
   description: "Network Error"
   message: "Network Error"

   request: Object
   response: undefined
   stack: "Error: Network Error at e.exports 
   (https://unpkg.com/axios@0.18.0/dist/axios.min.js:8:4473) at l.onerror 
   (https://unpkg.com/axios@0.18.0/dist/axios.min.js:8:3317)"

   __proto__: Object
```

if we send get request without any header it will work fine.How can i call axios with header Authorization.

Thank you

Comment: Is the token correct?
Try adding the header to the instance: 

axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + token;
axios.get(url).then(...)